# Phantom exception stops execution of child method, but doesn't bubble up

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function that executes in response to an SNS message. There is some inexplicable behavior happening where execution stops in child method suddenly (as if an exception is thrown), but the parent continues executing as normal afterward.

```
public void InsertEntity(Entity entity)
{
    _context.Entities.Add(entity);

    _logger.Log($"Before SaveChanges, entity.Id is {entity.Id}");

    _context.SaveChanges();

    _logger.Log($"After SaveChanges, entity.Id is {entity.Id}");

    if (entity.Id < 0)
        throw new Exception($"InsertEntity succeeded, but id is invalid: {entity.Id}");
}

public int? ImportEntity(string xml)
{
    var entity = new Entity(xml);

    _entityRepository.InsertEntity(entity);

    _logger.LogLine($"Entity inserted successfully with Id {entity.Id}");

    return entity.Id;
}
```

The context in this case is a standard DbContext using a PostgreSQL EF provider.

When the entity is first created, the Id is 0. When you add it to the context DbSet, the id becomes a temporary negative integer like `-2147392341`. After SaveChanges is called, the entity should be given an Id from the database, a positive number.

Any exceptions here should bubble up to the method that calls ImportEntity and it should handle the error. Instead my log file in AWS looks like this:

```
Before SaveChanges, entity.Id is -2147482647
Entity inserted successfully with Id -2147482647
```

And the negative value is being returned with no exception thrown at any point. Since I have code inside InsertEntity that specifically checks for a negative value, the only possibility I can see is that SaveChanges is throwing an exception that is causing both the logging and the negative check to not be run. But how does the parent method continue logging and executing and returning a value?

I know my code is being updated on AWS because I added the "Before SaveChanges" logging recently and it's showing up, and I added the logging all at the same time.

**EDIT**:

I added a try/catch directly around the `_context.SaveChanges();` and was able to catch the underlying exception. The question still remains of why/how it's possible for execution to continue in the `ImportEntity` function even when an exception is being thrown from within `InsertEntity`.

**EDIT 2**:

Adding csproj definition:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>MyService</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <PackageId>MyService</PackageId>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="runtimes\linux\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.3.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.S3Events" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.XRay" Version="3.3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSXRayRecorder" Version="2.0.0-beta" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSXRayRecorder.Handlers.AwsSdk" Version="2.0.0-beta" />
    <PackageReference Include="Castle.Core" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore" Version="1.5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.SNSEvents" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NetworkInformation" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService" Version="3.3.0.24" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.Tools" Version="2.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And the top-level lambda method which is called by AWS, and in return calls ImportEntity:

```
public void ProcessEntity(SNSEvent evnt, ILambdaContext context)
{
    var fileContent = GetFileContent(evnt);

    using (var lifetimeScope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        var processor = processingScope.Resolve<IEntityProcessor>();
        var result = processor.ImportEntity(fileContent);

        context.Logger.LogLine($"Successfully imported entity, Id is {result.Value}");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that somwhere along your stack trace you are invoking this logic in separate thread that you are not waiting to finish?

Comment: All of my code is in a synchronous lambda function. However, I'm not sure it should matter? I understand how tasks and thread exceptions don't bubble to other threads, but why would one method (`ImportEntity`) calling another method (`InsertEntity`) continue execution and ignore the exception? Even if it were on its own thread, that thread would terminate.

Comment: Which logs are you referring to?  The CloudWatch logs? If there are uncaught exceptions you should see them there

Comment: @TrevorElliott also, what was the exception caught when you wrapped the save changes?

Comment: There are a lot of details missing from the sample provided. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. This would help us in understanding the issue and aid in looking for a solution.

Comment: Yes, those are the CloudWatch logs I'm looking at. The underlying exception is an EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException from the Postgres EF core provider related to a unique constraint violation.

Comment: This code snippet is complete in the scope of the problem at hand: how does `"Entity inserted successfully with Id {entity.Id}"`, a string which only appears in that one line in my entire repo, get logged immediately after `"Before SaveChanges, entity.Id is {entity.Id}"`, without `"After SaveChanges, entity.Id is {entity.Id}"` ever being logged? As far as I know this cannot happen in C#.

Comment: @TrevorElliott it's not enough to reproduce the issue, which would allow people to diagnose it properly.  It did actually occur to me to close this question as offtopic.

Comment: @Mick If you could suggest a possible scenario in which the code outside of this code, which calls ImportEntity, could cause this logging behavior, I would love to hear it. Even just one technically plausible explanation. If I could reproduce it locally I wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: @TrevorElliott the point of supplying a complete code sample is that it eliminates the need for speculation, which is all you're going to get with what you've supplied.

Comment: The issue might be not with the code, but with the assembly or with the runtime. Do you use aspect programming? Something like Fody? Methods hot-patching? There might be a try-catch guard introduced either by some generated code or by generated IL code.

Comment: It is virtually impossible for the 2nd log line to print without your (temporary) try-catch _and_ for you to catch an exception when you temporarily add it, with the code shown. There must be something else going on, perhaps AOP-like, perhaps AWS messing with your binary (unlikely in this context I'd have thought), that we can't see above. Are those methods quoted verbatim in the question?

Comment: Yes, the inner methods are almost exactly verbatim. And yes, I've shown the actual source code to 3 other developers at my company, and nobody can explain the behavior. Which is why I tagged this question for AWS lambdas running .NET core.

Comment: if we knew what exception it was throwing in that try catch it would help

Answer (score 4):

This problem has been seen before, many times. I suspect the root cause is similar to what happens when an unawaited async process throws exceptions: they don't bubble to your code because they're not designed to do so.

In other cases where this kind of thing has been resolved the root failure is typically external to your code, meaning somewhere in the database connection, mapping, or even on the database side itself. When that happens the thread simply dies and execution continues as if SaveChanges had returned normally.

A database timeout can cause this behavior.  Something like a POCO file that doesn't match the database correctly can cause it too, and you likely won't get a warning. A confusion between 32-bit and 64-bit file locations can cause it. If the database is transactional and the dirty ObjectStateEntry objects can't be persisted, a failure of any transaction will cause this.

I'd start by looking at the error logs on your database -- it's surprising how often the problem becomes obvious when you do that. If logs don't show the problem, then put instrumentation on the database side and look at the received query, the query result, and the query execution. That will very likely point you in the right direction.

If this doesn't get you unblocked, it would be worth the time to make a complete and executable minimal repro and post it. That would give me what I'd need to track down the source of the problem.